# Marketing Cloud: Using a Shared IP with SAP (Sender Authentication Package)? Possible?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sender-authentication-package

Is it possible for a client to purchase SAP (Sender Authentication Package) *but* use a shared IP?  SAP comes with a dedicated IP and I can't find anywhere saying if it's required to have or not.  The client's email send volume is very low, so a shared IP is the best for them right now, but they want the branding, RMM, etc. - everything else that comes with SAP.

Comment: This doesn't sound like it's a question about _Salesforce_, but rather about SAP. Can you clarify how this is related to Salesforce? Your best option might be to contact the support staff for SAP or read the documentation that SAP provides.

Comment: @DerekF SAP stands for Sender Authentication Package, which is an add-on to Marketing Cloud.  Has nothing to do with SAP software.  Sorry for the confusion, I edited the question to include that abbreviation meaning so people don't get confused.

Comment: I've swapped your tags for you so that other people don't get confused. As always, the safest option is to use the full version before using an initialism or abbreviation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can have this configuration:

> If you send less than 100,000 messages per month, you can still benefit from authentication of SAP and request to remain on our shared IPs or share another IP within your account structure. This option must be clearly stated in any SAP submission or else a dedicated IP is assigned to the account.

[Source](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_sap.htm&type=5)